# Passport.js Successful Login hangs without error using MySQL and Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to create an application that utilizes a registration and login functionality. I have completed the registration portion where all the information (Email and Password) is successfully passed and saved into a MySQL database.

**Problem:** My issue now is that when I put in any existing credential and email, the application will hang and refuse to redirect the user to a new page. On the bottom of my browser, it will say "Waiting for localhost...". If I leave the page up for too long, it'll eventually lead to an error page with the words "This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I tried console logging for any errors but was unable to identify any causes/errors. I did ensure that the information I inputted is properly being compared to the values in the database table and that the redirection to the page is functioning. I also tried rewriting my code in multiple ways but ended up encountering the same issue.

Below is my **passport.js** file:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

// Reference: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
            // Match user
            User.findOne({ which: { email: email } })
                .then(user => {
                    // Check if Email exists in database
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, {
                            message: "Email is not registered."
                        });
                    }

                    // Check if password matches the one found in the database (To Do: Encrypt this later!)
                    if (password != user.password) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password is incorrect.' });
                    } else {
                        return done(null, user);
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
    );

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        // Find by Primary Key
        User.findByPk(id, function (err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

Below is my **app.js** (server) file:

```
var express = require('express')
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

var app = express();

// Embedded JavaScript (EJS)
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Bodyparser 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Connect flash for notification messages
app.use(flash());

// Global Variables to define specific notification messages
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Notification for Registration Page
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg')
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');

    // Notification for Passport Login Verification
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));

// Login/Register Endpoints routes (ex. /users/login)
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

// Image
//app.use(express.static('./public'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8026;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server Running');
console.log("Port: " + port);
```

Below is my **function** to handle the login and redirection:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Please let me know if you need any other information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the hanging issue. It was indeed something wrong with the way I wrote **passport.js** as the code works more for MongoDB rather than MySQL.

Here is the new working **passport.js**:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        connection.query("select * from users where id = "+id,function(err,rows){   
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows pass back of entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from form
         // Match User
         connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '" + email + "'",function(err,rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
             // Check if Email exists in database
             if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' }); 
            } 

            // Check if password matches the one found in the database (To Do: Encrypt this later!)
            if (!( rows[0].password == password))
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Password is incorrect.' });

            // All is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);         
        });
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a problem. On `passport.use` , if an error occurred, you are not returning anything.

```
passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
            // Match user
            User.findOne({ which: { email: email } })
                .then(user => {
                    // Check if Email exists in database
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, {
                            message: "Email is not registered."
                        });
                    }

                    // Check if password matches the one found in the database (To Do: Encrypt this later!)
                    if (password != user.password) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password is incorrect.' });
                    } else {
                        return done(null, user);
                    }
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                           console.log(err));
                           return done(null, false, { message: 'Internal Server error.' });
                           }
        })
```

Comment: I gave this a go but did not receive any error messages. When I commit the login with the correct credentials, this is what appears in the console.log ```Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `date` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3```. This links to the correct information in the database, but it still hangs.